# PHP: grabbing multiple files types using GLOB

Tags: php, image, random, glob

i've been looking around SO for an answer, but I quite can't figure out why my code isn't working. I'm trying to grab all picture files from a directory (multiple file extensions, jpg,gif,png,etc) and put it in an array. The problem is with my GLOB code, it only grabs 1 jpg image (the same one every time), despite others being in there.

```
 $imagesDir = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TV\images';
 $images = glob($imagesDir . '/*.{jpg,png,gif,jgeg,svg,bmp}', GLOB_BRACE);
 $images2 = glob($imagesDir . '/*.*', GLOB_BRACE); 
 $images3 = glob("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TV\images.{*jpg,*png,*gif,*bmp,*jpeg,*svg}",      
 GLOB_BRACE);
```

I was trying to put the path into the glob command itself, but I couldn't work the syntax.

$images only grabs only a specific jpg file (despite all 7 being jpg though) in the array.
$images2 successfully grabs all images in the array (but includes all types of file paths).
$images3 straight doesn't work.

My only guess is that the $images only grabs a 1 file and then calls it quits. I was wondering why it wasn't grabbing all of pictures in the directory.

Edit: Putting it in a foreach loop still doesn't work:

```
foreach (glob($imagesDir . '/*.{jpg,gif,jgeg,svg,bmp}', GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
    array_push($images, $filename);
}
```

returns the same image (it is 'always' IMG_8646, despite others jpg images being in there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best to use an interator [DirectoryInterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php), here's a code snippet:-

```
$valid_ext = array("jpg", "gif", "jpeg", "svg", "bmp"); // valid extensions

foreach (new DirectoryIterator($imagesDir) as $fileInfo) { // interator
    if (in_array($fileInfo->getExtension(), $valid_ext) ) { // in $valid_ext
        echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . "<br>\n"; // do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: use `$fileinfo->isFile()` to make sure you are not grabbing directory that is named `folder.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `foreach(){}` to iterate though the glob function. as

```
 foreach (glob('/path/to/images/*.jpg') as $filename) {
    //echo file name
 }
```

Comment: I figured I'd have to put it in a for loop.

does the glob function work differently? just out of curiosity (if anyone knows) why the glob function can grab all files when the filetype is not described, whereas defining the types limits it to only 1 file?

Comment: in other words, is this impossible to do with just 1 glob call?

Comment: I don't know how pattern decides how many files it can grab, but I would probably just grab all files, and use getimagetype() function to show only the desired images